# Spring boot Hibernate call stored procedure error "Cannot get the describe information"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to call a DB2 stored procedure, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Hibernate: {call MYSPNAME(?,?,?)}
2020-03-18T18:14:53,707 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper id= marker= - SQL Error: -4472, SQLState: null
2020-03-18T18:14:53,718 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper id= marker= - [jcc][10453][12709][4.11.77] Cannot get the describe information for the calling stored procedure with name MYSPNAME and path ' SYSIBM , SYSFUN , SYSPROC , SYSIBMADM , MY_USERNAME ' ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
2020-03-18T18:14:53,733 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper id= marker= - SQL Warning Code: 4223, SQLState: null
2020-03-18T18:14:53,733 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper id= marker= - Origination unknown: [10228][11541][4.11.77] Security exceptions occurred while loading driver. ERRORCODE=4223, SQLSTATE=null
```

My **NamedStoredProcedureQuery**:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name="MYSPNAME",
    procedureName="MYSPNAME",
    resultClasses={ MyEntity.class },
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="USERID", type=String.class,   mode=ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="APPNM",  type=String.class,   mode=ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="DATE",   type=String.class,   mode=ParameterMode.IN)
    }
)
```

How I call it:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MYSPNAME");
query.setParameter("USERID", "Test");
query.setParameter("APPNM", "Test");
query.setParameter("DATE", "Test");

query.getResultList();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are there security exceptions? I looked online and found that the error "Cannot get the describe information" only happens on an older driver version from mine. Any information would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the target database running on Db2-for-Z/OS (mainframe) or i-series? The first exception (-4472 sqlcode) means "The requested operation cannot be performed because the target resource is unavailable.", . Try , adding to your connection string `retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;` to see if you can get more details about the error.

Comment: It is z/OS. Did you mean to add it at the end of the "jdbc://" string? If so, it didn't return back any extra details. Thank you though.

Comment: Please answer the question re Db2-for-Z/os.  To see if you can get more details, Try calling the stored procedure from a plain jdbc app (i.e. not using hibernate, just a simple test case), and catch all SQLException , then print each exception getMessage() and getErrorCode output (until no more exceptions are returned by getNextException.